# chroot with unionfs-fuse, can't access /dev/*

Tags: mount, devices, chroot, unionfs

I have created the a chroot jail in combination with unionfs-fuse so that I don't need to install another system inside it.

However, the resulting system's /dev entries are not readable.This is causing problems with programs needing access to `/dev/random`, `/dev/null` and `/dev/urandom`.

I tried to solve the issue myself by making a directory consisting of persistent files and making equivalents of the aforementioned files using `mknod` as described [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Chroot-BIND-HOWTO-2.html), and then creating an unionfs:

```
# unionfs-fuse -o cow /chroot/files=RW:/chroot/persistent/:/ /chroot/chroot/
```

And then,

```
# chroot chroot/
```

But, when I try to:

```
# head -c 10 /dev/random | hexdump -C
```

I get the error:

```
head: cannot open `/dev/random' for reading: Permission denied
```

How should I work around this problem?

(I do not need access to other files in `/dev` like `/dev/sd*` or `/dev/mem`.)

Comment: `unionfs` is just one big conglomeration of ugly hacks stacked one upon the other. skip it - use shared mount trees instead. your problem is probably related to the fuse aspect though - which is probably also a word that should send up a few alarms in your head.

Comment: By the way, take care with `/` in your union filesystem: that creates an infinite path `/chroot/chroot/chroot/chroot/…`. Make sure that `locate` and other recursive jobs won't traverse it ad infinitum.

Comment: @Gilles - you need to `mount --make-unbindable /chroot; mount --bind / /chroot` to handle that w/ a vanilla-kernel - dunno how to address it *(or if it can be addressed)* with `unionfs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation lies in the [`mount.fuse` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mount.fuse.8.html):

> Filesystems are mounted with `nodev,nosuid` by default, which can only be overridden by a privileged user

With the `nodev` option, the kernel bans all access to devices in the mounted filesystem. With the `nosuid` option, the kernel ignores setuid and setgid attributes. Both options are necessary for security when a filesystem is mounted by a non-root user: otherwise the mounting user could create a setuid root shell or devices letting him access all disks bypassing the filesystem.

You'll also want the `allow_other` option if non-root users are to access that filesystem.

```
unionfs-fuse -o cow,dev,suid,allow_other /chroot/files=RW:/chroot/persistent/:/ /chroot/chroot/
```

If you want to restrict which devices are visible in the chroot, then a union mount isn't the way to do that. Instead, leave `dev` off and mount a separate filesystem containing your desired minimal `/dev`. You can make that a tmpfs:

```
unionfs-fuse -o cow,suid,allow_other /chroot/files=RW:/chroot/persistent/:/ /chroot/chroot/
mount -t tmpfs -o mode=755 chroot-dev /chroot/chroot/dev
cp -a /dev/null /dev/zero /dev/urandom /chroot/chroot/dev
mkdir /chroot/chroot/dev/pts
mount --bind /dev/pts /chroot/chroot/dev/pts
```

Instead of a tmpfs, you could bind-mount a directory containing your devices ready to go. You'll need to bind-mount `/dev/pts` to get pseudoterminals in the chroot.

Comment: Is there a way to allow devices only from a specific location (which would be my own versions of `/dev/{null,random,urandom}`present in `/chroot/persistent`, as discussed above)? Security is an important consideration as this is a chroot jail.

Comment: @user2064000 I don't think you can get that degree of control. I think the best solution would be to mount a static `/dev` on top of the union filesystem, either by bind-mounting a directory or by creating a tiny tmpfs in your mount script.

Comment: @user2064000 (see edit) Also you'll need `/dev/pts` in the chroot.